# Failing to understand a lemma regarding Robust Low Rank Approximation

Tags: approximation-algorithms, randomized-algorithms, clustering

I am reading [Low Rank Approximation in the Presence of
Outliers](https://drops.dagstuhl.de/opus/volltexte/2018/9408/pdf/LIPIcs-APPROX-RANDOM-2018-4.pdf) by Bhaskara and Kumar and kind of stuck at the proof of Lemma 9. The paper studies robust (to outliers) low rank approximation problem. Given a matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{d\times n}$ ($n$ points in $\mathbb{R}^d$), the problem asks to find a decomposition $A=B+N$, where $N$ (outliers) can have at most $m$ non-zero columns such that the minimum rank-$k$ approximation (under Frobenius norm) of $B$ (inliers) is minimized over all such decomposition of $A$. In other words, given a point set $P$, parition this into $I$(inliers) and $O$(outliers) such that $\vert O\vert\leq m$ and cost of the best fit $k$-subspace of $I$ (sum of squared distance of $I$ to this subspace is minimized among all such $k$-subspace) is minimized among all such partition of $P$. I will be using the former terminology, conforming to the paper.

In section 4 of the aforementioned paper, they give a randomized approximation algorithm for the problem. I am interested in Lemma 6,8 and 9 of the paper.

> **Lemma 6** basically says that uniform random sampling we can find a $poly(k/\epsilon)$ dimensional space which covers a constant factor of the points, without the presence of outliers. More formally, let $S$ be a uniform random subset (without replacemet) of size $s\geq \frac{4k}{\epsilon^2}$ of $[n]$. Then with probability at least $\epsilon^2/8$ the following holds : there is a subset T of at least $\epsilon^2n/8$ columns of $A$ such that $\forall u\in T$, $\Vert u - proj_S(u)\Vert^2 \leq (1+\epsilon)\frac{\Vert A-A_k\Vert^2_F}{n}$. Here $proj_S(u)$ is the orthogonal projection of $u$ onto $span(S)$ and $A_k$ is the best rank-$k$ approximation of $A$.

Lemma 6 asserts only the existence of $T$ (even when there is no outliers). The next best thing is to choose the closest $\epsilon^2n/8$ columns of $A$ to $span(S)$. Let $X$ be this set of columns. Since $\vert X\vert \leq \vert T\vert$, it follows that

> $\forall x\in X, \Vert x-proj_S(x)\vert^2 \leq \max_{u\in T}\Vert u - proj_S(u)\Vert^2 \leq (1+\epsilon)\frac{\Vert A-A_k\Vert^2_F}{n}$.

In presence of outliers, the situation is changed somewhat. Suppose $A=B+N$ is the optimal decomposition of $A$ and $B_k$ is best rank-$k$ approximation of $B$. We can **assume** that the columns of $B$ are arranged in increasing order in their squared distance from $B_k$. Let $Q$ be the first $\epsilon\vert B\vert$ columns of $B$. Of course we do not know $B$, we can not directly sample from $B$.

> **Lemma 8** says that if we sample enough columns from $A$, then with some probability we would sample at least $4k/\epsilon^2$ from $Q$ , so that we can apply Lemma 6, replacing $A$ of the lemma with $Q$. Since the success probability is only $\Omega(\epsilon^2)$, we repeat the sampling step $O(\log n/\epsilon^2)$ times to boost the success probability to $1-1/n^{O(1)}$. This is also true for any subset of columns of $A$.

This two lemma naturally gives rise to a recursive algorithm :

1. START WITH $A$.
2. APPLY LEMMA 8 (WHICH IMPLICITLY INVOKES LEMMA 6) AND LET $X^\star$ BE THE BEST AMONG $O(\log n/\epsilon^2)$ SAMPLING STEPS AND $S^\star$ BE ITS CORRESPONDING RANDOM SAMPLE. (meaning $\sum_{x\in X^\star}\Vert x - proj_{S^\star}(x)\Vert^2$ is minimum among all the sampling steps).
3. MARK $X^\star$ AS COVERED AND REMOVE $X^\star$ FROM $A$ AND GO TO STEP 1(unless the number of columns left in $A$ is already small).

**Lemma 9** analyze the above algorithm (the algorithm presented here is incomplete but gives the basic flavor, as it is not possible to find such a decomposition in polynomial time where there is exactly $m$ outliers, under some complexity theoretic conjecture. So some slack must be incorporated, see Algorithm 2 of the paper).

**The basic idea that lemma 8 enables us to "cover" smallest (in terms of the optimal projection cost) $\epsilon$-fraction of the remaining inliers**. Let $X_i^\star$ be the $X^\star$ in the $i$th recursive call and $S_i^\star$ be its corresponding sample and define $n^\prime = n-m$. Let $G_1$ be the first $\epsilon n^\prime$ columns of $B$, $G_2$ be the next $\epsilon(1-\epsilon)n^\prime$ columns, $G_3$ be the next $\epsilon(1-\epsilon)^2n^\prime$ columns and so on and $E_i = \sum_{p\in G_i}\Vert p-proj_{B_k}(x)\Vert^2$ is the projection cost of $G_i$. Recall that the columns of $B$ are arranged in increasing order in their squared distance from $B_k$.

Let us consider the first iteration of the above algorithm. By Lemma 6 and 8 we have that

> $\forall x\in X_1^\star, \Vert x-proj_{S_1^\star}(x)\vert^2 \leq (1+\epsilon)\frac{E_1}{\vert G_1\vert}$.

Now the authors claim that **"untill the algorithm marks $\epsilon n^\prime$ columns as covered, we have that average error in the marked columns is at most $(1+\epsilon)\frac{E_2}{\vert G_2\vert}$"**. `I fail to understand this precise statement`. I think what the authors meant is as follows: Let $I$ be the largest index such that $\vert \cup_{i=1}^I X_i^\star\vert \leq \epsilon n^\prime$. Then for $i=1,\cdots, I$

> $\forall x\in X_i^\star, \Vert x-proj_{S_i^\star}(x) \Vert^2 \leq (1+\epsilon)\frac{E_2}{\vert G_2\vert}$.

Now if this statement is true (i am unable to prove this), then the total projection cost is bounded by $(1+\epsilon)\frac{\vert G_1\vert}{\vert G_2\vert}E_2 = \frac{1+\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}E_2$, which is what the authors want. The basic difficulty I am facing that the "remaining $\epsilon$-fraction of smallest inliers" depends on $X^\star$ and the author claim that whatever $X^\star$ be, till the point we remove at most $\epsilon n^\prime$ marked columns, the error remains bounded. I am more than sure I am missing something very trivial.

P.S. I am not sure whether this is the right platform to ask such elaborate question, but I have mailed the authors stating my doubts and awaiting a reply for quite some time. And I am not also sure what "tag" to put here. I would be immensely grateful if someone help me out here.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo the paper in question is a computer science paper so I naturally thought this community will br more suitable